# What's the difference of dmesg output and /var/log/messages?

Tags: kernel, logs, dmesg

AFAIK `dmesg` shows information about kernel and kernel modules, and `/var/log/messages` also shows information produced by kernel and modules.

So what's the difference? Does `/var/log/messages` [⊂](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) output of `dmesg`?

More Info that may be helpful:
- There is a [kernel ring buffer](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/trace/ring-buffer-design.txt), which I think is the very and only place to store kernel log data.
- Article "[Kernel logging: APIs and implementation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-kernel-logging-apis/index.html)" on IBM DeveloperWorks described APIs and the bird-view picture.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`dmesg` prints the contents of the ring buffer.  This information is also sent in real time to `syslogd` or `klogd`, when they are running, and ends up in `/var/log/messages`; when `dmesg` is most useful is in capturing boot-time messages from before `syslogd` and/or `klogd` started, so that they will be properly logged.

Comment: So `/var/log/messages` and `dmesg` will show the same logs (in different format) after `syslogd` and/or `klogd` started?

Comment: After `klogd` is running, `dmesg` will show only the most recent kernel messages (because the ring buffer is a fixed size and so can only hold so much), without timestamps or other information, while `/var/log/messages` will retain logs according to how `logrotate` is configured and include timestamping (which will be slightly inaccurate for initial boot messages because `dmesg` doesn't have them, so the time `klogd` started is used for all messages read from the kernel buffer).

Comment: @xanpeng `dmesg` only contains messages from the kernel, `/var/log/messages` usually contains logs from applications as well.

Answer (score 18):

That depends on the operating system. For example on Solaris, [dmesg](https://java.net/projects/solaris/sources/on-src/content/usr/src/cmd/dmesg/dmesg.sh?rev=13149) is simply a shell script showing the last 200 lines of the `/var/adm/messages.*` files.

Comment: Is it colorful too?

Comment: @Hi-Angel No post-processing of the log file so no coloring, just `cat ... | tail -200`.

Answer (score 11):

- We can say that `dmesg` is the subset of `/var/log/messages` and is maintained in ring buffer.
- `/var/log/messages` includes all the system messages including from starting of the system along with the messages in `dmesg`. In a nutshell logs from `dmesg` are dumped in `/var/log/messages`.
- `/var/log/messages` maintain the general system activity logs and `dmesg` maintains only the kernel logs.

Answer (score 5):

**dmesg** :  dmesg is an (display or driver) message. It is used to examine or    control the kernel ring buffer.

**messages** : It contains global system messages, including the messages that are logged during system startup. There are several things that are logged in `/var/log/messages` including mail, cron, daemon, kern, auth, etc.