# dmesg display packet info while journalctl --dmesg show none on my centos?

Tags: centos, iptables, logs

```
# cat /proc/version 
Linux version 2.6.32-042stab125.5 (root@kbuild-rh6-x64.eng.sw.ru) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Oct 17 12:48:22 MSK 2017
```

For the logging chain in my iptables.

```
Chain LOGGING (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "drop port 22"
```

Inspect all logging records.

```
# dmesg 
RGP=0 
[404925.404804] drop port 22IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=111.111.111.111 DST=222.222.222.222 LEN=136 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=45 ID=23569 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=25103 DPT=22 WINDOW=282 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[404955.495105] drop port 22IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=111.111.111.111 DST=222.222.222.222 LEN=136 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=34883 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=19703 DPT=22 WINDOW=296 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

Nothing as output for the following commands.

```
# journalctl --dmesg
-- No entries --
# cat  /var/log/dmesg
# cat  /var/log/messages |grep MAC
```

1. Which file contains all the info records displayed by dmesg?
2. Can journalctl command get all the output displayed by dmesg?
   Many records as the output of `dmesg` command, no entries for `journalctl --dmesg`,why?

Comment: Add your distribution to the question and tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dmesg` on Linux prints the output of the kernel ring buffer, not from a log file - which is why you can't find it. This might not be the case on other systems.  See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35851/whats-the-difference-of-dmesg-output-and-var-log-messages) for more details.

To view the same with `journalctl` use the `-k` or `--dmesg` option.

```
$ journalctl --dmesg
-- Logs begin at Mon 2017-10-23 19:04:10 BST, end at Sun 2017-11-12 08:39:58 GMT. --
Oct 23 19:04:10 HP-Envy kernel: microcode: CPU0 microcode updated early to revision 0x62, date = 2017-04-27
Oct 23 19:04:10 HP-Envy kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Oct 23 19:04:10 HP-Envy kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Oct 23 19:04:10 HP-Envy kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Oct 23 19:04:10 HP-Envy kernel: Linux version 4.4.0-89-generic (buildd@lgw01-18) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #112-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 31 19:38:41 UTC 2017 (Ubuntu 4.4.0-89.112-generic 4.4.76)
Oct 23 19:04:10 HP-Envy kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-89-generic root=UUID=a090cb63-4bf2-44e2-b7e1-cb5bd98cf75b ro quiet splash
Oct 23 19:04:10 HP-Envy kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
...
```

Note that while you can clear the ring buffer with `sudo dmesg clear` so that running `dmesg` yields no output, it is still stored in the journals and the above `journalctl` command will still work.

Comment: Many records as the output of dmesg command, no entries for journalctl --dmesg,why?

Comment: Pleae edit your question to a) add details of your distro, and b) replace the screen-shot with text.  A screen-shot cannot be read by search engines.

Answer (score 0):

1. **dmesg** entries are stored in /var/log/**syslog**
2. `journalctl -kf` should satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

The type of my vps is openvz ,test it on kvm, garethTheRed and Dr. Alexander  's command work.
In openvz's vps log will not written into  /var/log/syslog (debian) or /var/log/messages(centos).